# MS Access Db not saving in Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

1) I have problem that Code work properly at runtime and update data
    grid of windows form .net , but after close the form and when I
    check DB , the data not update there , (still the db unchanged )

2) I also have problem after publish , please see the image!

[image]

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load  
        Using con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\labprofiles.mdb;Persist Security Info=True")
            con.Open()
            Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("DELETE FROM Mint", con)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        End Using
        instrecall()
End Sub

Private Sub instrecall()
        Using con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\labprofiles.mdb;Persist Security Info=True")
            con.Open()
          Try
            Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("UPDATE int SET timespan = @timespan, nextscandue = @next  WHERE (type = 'folder')", con)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@timespan", 20)
            Dim nex As String = DateAndTime.Now.AddMinutes(20)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@next", nex)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            con.Close()
            con.Open()
            Dim cmd1 As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Mint SELECT * FROM int WHERE (type = 'folder')", con)
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
         Catch ex As Exception
           MsgBox(ex.ToString())
          End Try
        End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: try close connection after cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery(), add finally block to close connection, and because you have table name as int which is reserve keyword, so use brackets around  [int]

Comment: @ Piysuh , thanks its working now but 2 problem still same

Comment: int table name as an example , table name is different

Answer (score 0):

Close your connections once finished....

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load  
    Using con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\labprofiles.mdb;Persist Security Info=True")
        con.Open()
        Try
            Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("DELETE FROM Mint", con)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex as Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString())
        Finally
            con.Close()
        End Try
    End Using
    instrecall()
End Sub

Private Sub instrecall()
        Using con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\labprofiles.mdb;Persist Security Info=True")
            con.Open()
          Try
            Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("UPDATE Mint SET timespan = @timespan, nextscandue = @next  WHERE (type = 'folder')", con)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@timespan", 20)
            Dim nex As String = DateAndTime.Now.AddMinutes(20)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@next", nex)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            con.Close()
            con.Open()
            Dim cmd1 As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Mint SELECT * FROM int WHERE (type = 'folder')", con)
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
         Catch ex As Exception
           MsgBox(ex.ToString())
         Finally
           con.Close()
         End Try
     End Using
End Sub
```